# Recharts - Adjust the position of the yAxis cartesian grid

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, graph, frontend, recharts

How can I adjust my yAxis Cartesian grid to be at the start of the bar instead of the centre and also extend above the bar areas along the y-axis as shown in the second image.
[Click to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8j7qY.png)

Also how can I show the slope from one bar to the other as shown in the   diagram below?

[image]

Here is my code

```
       <ResponsiveContainer height={250} width={"100%"} >
        <BarChart data={data}>
          <YAxis
            dataKey="total"
            tickFormatter={(tick) => {
              if(tick >= 1000 && tick < 1000000) return ((tick / 1000) + 'K')
              else if (tick >= 1000000)return ((tick / 1000000) + 'M');
              else return tick;
            }}
            label={<AxisLabel>Number of Items</AxisLabel>}
          />
          <XAxis dx={-20} dataKey="product" xAxisId={0} tick={{ fontSize: 16 }} dy={10} />
          <XAxis dx={-20} dy={-10} orientation="top" xAxisId={1} dataKey="product" tick={{ fontSize: 16 }} />
          <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="8" stroke="#DFE2E6" />
          <Tooltip cursor={{ fill: "transparent" }} />
          {dataKeys && dataKeys.map((itemKey, idx) => 
          <Bar key={itemKey + idx} dataKey={itemKey} fill={colors[idx]} stackId="a" barSize={80}></Bar>)}
        </BarChart>
      </ResponsiveContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some really good examples what you can find around here:
http://recharts.org/en-US/

Also, check out this example:
http://recharts.org/en-US/examples/ComposedChartWithAxisLabels

This small snippet is basically based on the second one. Note that, to solve the grid adjusting, I simply added an empty bar to the left. This way only the stacked bars to the right will be visible.

To show the "slope" you simply add an area chart with the same values as your original data.

```
const data = [
  {
    name: 'Page A', uv: 96, pv: 800, amt: 800,
  },
  {
    name: 'Page B', uv: 452, pv: 967, amt: 967,
  },
  {
    name: 'Page C', uv: 512, pv: 1098, amt: 1098,
  },
  {
    name: 'Page D', uv: 248, pv: 1200, amt: 1200,
  },
  {
    name: 'Page E', uv: 300, pv: 1108, amt: 1108,
  },
  {
    name: 'Page F', uv: 185, pv: 680, amt: 680,
  },
];

class Example extends PureComponent {

  render() {
    return (
      <ComposedChart
        width={500}
        height={400}
        data={data}
        margin={{
          top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20,
        }}
      >
        <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="8" stroke="#DFE2E6" />
        <XAxis type="category" dataKey="name" />
        <YAxis type="number" />
        <Tooltip />
        <Legend />
        <Area dataKey="amt" fill="#808080" stroke="#505050" />
        <Bar dataKey="" barSize={20} fill="#ffffffff" />
        <Bar dataKey="pv" stackId="a" barSize={20} fill="#413ea0" />
        <Bar dataKey="uv" stackId="a" barSize={20} fill="#909090" />
      </ComposedChart>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can target the y Axis with

```
 .recharts-yAxis .recharts-text {
    transform: translate(-50px, 0);
 }
```

or just add `tick={{ dx: -7 }}`

```
   <YAxis
        dataKey="total"
        tick={{ dx: -7 }}
        tickFormatter={(tick) => {
          if(tick >= 1000 && tick < 1000000) return ((tick / 1000) + 'K')
          else if (tick >= 1000000)return ((tick / 1000000) + 'M');
          else return tick;
        }}
        label={<AxisLabel>Number of Items</AxisLabel>}
      />
```